# Why my CPU frequencies high but application performance is poor

Tags: performance, cpu, raspberrypi, c++

I have two similar raspberry pi running Ubuntu with little difference in their configuration. I am trying to monitor their performance for running my application. So I am running my app on both raspberry pi and logging frequencies of all cores. First pi throttles the cores a lot but second throttles the core less. However, single iteration time in my application is lesser on first pi is lesser than that on second pi. I felt high throttling will result in higher single iteration time. But that does not seem to be the case. So, I am trying to investigate the same.

Though I ensured that both pi have exactly same software environment and have same set processes running, it might be possible that I have missed something.

I was thinking how can I un earth the reason behind this. One approach will be to log % CPU utilization of top 5 processes along with CPU core frequencies and the cpu utilization by my application. After that comparing these readings on two pi's should give some insights. But how do I do this / how can I log this information, say after 100th iteration in my C++ application?

Also is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? The default OS of Raspberry Pi is the Debian based Raspberry Pi OS, which is not supported on this site.

Comment: Try `time programname` and `man time`  for more info.

Comment: What product are you using?  Ubuntu Core is somewhat difference by design to Ubuntu Server for example, and if your systems are running different OSes, differences can be expected & you didn't provide specifics.

Comment: OSs are Ubuntu 18.04 vs Ubuntu 20.04